# Q_ARG Missing from PySide - How to proceed?

Tags: python, pyside

I've hit a problem working with PySide [Python 3.3.3 / PySide 1.2.1] and invokeMethod - it seems PySide doesn't have the Q_ARG macro baked in.

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.worker, '_reader_run_mfoc_dummy',
                                             QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
                                             QtCore.Q_ARG(str, self.get_keys_filename()),
                                             QtCore.Q_ARG(str, self.get_dump_filename()))
```

returns:

```
QtCore.Q_ARG(str, self.get_keys_filename()),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Q_ARG'
```

Despite warnings from the Documents not to do so, even if I try to pass a generic argument, it fails (but for a different reason):

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.worker, '_reader_run_mfoc_dummy',
                                             QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
                                             QtCore.QGenericArgument("str",self.get_keys_filename()),
                                             QtCore.QGenericArgument("str",self.get_dump_filename()))
```

> QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method Worker::_reader_run_mfoc_dummy(str,str)

Despite my Slot / Method signature being:

```
@QtCore.Slot(str, str)
def _reader_run_mfoc_dummy(self, keys_filename, dump_filename):
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get around this problem?
I'm unsure why it fails to find the target method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in PySide. `invokeMethod` doesn't work currently with arguments in PySide. Use `QtCore.QTimer.singleshot(..)` or send an Event or emit a Signal instead.

See my question [QMetaObject::invokeMethod doesn't find methods with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538904/qmetaobjectinvokemethod-doesnt-find-methods-with-parameters) here. Also you should use `QString` instead of `str` in QGenericArgument but then Python will crash.

Comment: Yeah, qthread related things are really buggy in PySide. PyQt is much better.