# migrating from Inherited QThread to Worker model

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside, qthread

So through a lot of help in my previous questions
([Interrupting QThread sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119319/interrupting-qthread-sleep)
and [PySide passing signals from QThread to a slot in another QThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173560/pyside-passing-signals-from-qthread-to-a-slot-in-another-qthread)) I decided to attempt to change from the inherited `QThread` model to the Worker model. I am thinking I should stay with the `QThread` model as I had that working, and the other model is not. However I am not sure why the Worker model isn't working for me.

I am attempting to do this please let me know if there is something inherently wrong in my methodology?

I have a `QtGui.QWidget` that is my main GUI. I am using a `QPushButton` to signal 
I have attempted to reduce the code to the basics of where I believe the issue is. I have verified that `datagramHandled` `Signal` gets emitted but the `packet_handled` `Slot` doesn't seem to get called.

```
class myObject(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myObject, self).__init__()
        self.ready=False

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def do_work(self):
        #send a packet
        self.ready=False
        while not self.ready:
            time.sleep(0.01)

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def packet_handled(self, errorCode):
        print "Packet received."
        self.ready = True

class myWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    datagramHandled = QtCore.Signal(int)
    startRunThread = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self,parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        # Bunch of GUI setup stuff (working)
        self.myRunThread = QtCore.QThread()
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def run_command(self):
        self.myRunObj = myObject()
        self.myRunObj.moveToThread(self.myRunThread)
        self.datagramHandled.connect(self.myRunObj.packet_handled)
        self.startRunThread.connect(self.myRunObj.do_work)
        self.myRunThread.start()
        self.startRunThread.emit()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def handle_datagram(self):
        #handle the incoming datagram
        errorCode = 0
        self.datagramHandled.emit(errorCode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you need to connect your `myObject.do_work` method to `QThread.started`:

```
self.myRunThread.started.connect(self.myRunObj.do_work)
```

Secondly, your `do_work` method should include something along these lines to enable event processing (please forgive my rusty PyQt and pseudocode):

```
def do_work(self):
    while someCondition:
        #The next two lines are critical for events and queued signals
        if self.thread().eventDispatcher().hasPendingEvents():
            self.thread().eventDispatcher().processEvents(QEventLoop.AllEvents)
        if not self.meetsSomeConditionToContinueRunning():
            break
        elif self.hasWorkOfSomeKind():
            self.do_something_here()
        else:
            QThread.yieldCurrentThread()
```

For more on this, check out the docs for [`QAbstractEventDispatcher`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracteventdispatcher.html#processEvents).

The logic here is that when a signal is emitted from one thread (`myWidget.datagramHandled`), it gets queued in your worker thread's event loop. Calling `processEvents` processes any pending events (including queued signals, which are really just events), invoking the appropriate slots for any queued signals (`myRunObj.packet_handled`).

Further reading:

- [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads; The Full Explanation](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)
- [Threading Basics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html)

Comment: I am confusing myself I think with the first part, maybe it makes more sense if I don't use `run()` Why connect to `self.myRunThread.run` when I am calling `self.myRunThread.start()`

Comment: Whoops. I meant to connect it to `myRunThread.start`. I corrected my answer. If you're calling it manually, the signal/slot connection is not necessary.

Comment: OK. Also, FWIW I renamed `run` to `do_work` in my question, I started getting confusing it with `run()` from `QThread` (I should have renamed it when I converted it from a `QThread` class to a `QObject` class

Comment: I've updated my answer and removed the unnecessary signal connection.

Answer (score 3):

There 3 possible ways of distributing the computation/other load with Qt:

1. Explicitly putting the load to concrete `QThread` instance. That is *thread-based concurrency*.
2. Implicitly putting the load to pooled `QThread` instance. That is closer to task-based concurrency yet 'manually' managed with your own logic. `QThreadPool` class is used for maintaining the pool of threads.
3. Starting the task in own threading context we never explicitly manage. That is *task-based concurrency* and [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) namespace used. My guess is that task-based concurrency and "worker model" is the same thing (observed your changes). Mind that `QtConcurrent` does offer parallelization for tasks and uses exceptions (which may affect the way you write the code) unlike the rest of Qt.

Given you use PyQt you can also take an advantage of the feature designated for the pattern you want to implement with [QtConcurrent for PyQt](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QtConcurrent.html).

P.S. I see use `thread.sleep( interval )` and that is not a good practice and one more indication that the proper technique should be used for implementing 'Worker model'.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the solution provided by @JonHarper is to replace your `while` loop with a `QTimer`. Because you have an event loop running in your worker process now, it can handle `QTimer` events correctly (as long as you construct the `QTimer` in the relevant thread).

This way, control is returned to the event loop periodically so that other slots can be run when required.